# Как сделать отступы между блоками div, чтобы они не были впритык?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Всем привет. Только начал изучать bootstrap (3 версия), поэтому есть трудности (даже в терминологии). Возник такой вопрос: как отделить блоки div друг от друга? Имею в виду, чтобы на сайте содержимое этих блоков не было впритык. Вот например у меня есть 2 div-а, как написать, чтобы на сайте выглядело раздельно?

```html
<body>

    <div class="row form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-15">
            <label class="small">Варианты</label>
            <select class="form-control" title="" name="testGroup" id="testGroup194">
                <option selected="selected" value="">ALL</option>
                <option title="Вариант A" value="14">Вариант A</option>
                <option title="Вариант B" value="15">Вариант B</option>
                <option title="Вариант C" value="16">Вариант C</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-16">
            <label class="small">Название</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="patientName">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Также вопрос по коду (он не мой). Что значит col-sm-15 и col-sm-16? Это же вроде сетка, в которой максимум 12 столбцов возможно.

Comment: в 4.5 версии есть уже встроенные классы для организации отступов https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/

Comment: @AndreyMaslov, мне нужен способ в 3 версии bootstrap-а

Comment: а в чем проблема подключить 4ую версию bootstrap? Они обратно совместимы, так что все будет в порядке

Answer (score 1):

Например, добавить класс `mr-10`, он означает `margin-right: 10px`.

Comment: Извините за глупые вопросы, но куда конкретно нужно добавить этот класс в моём коде?

Comment: к диву, как если бы вы его стилизовали

Comment: Я добавил mr-10 к диву, но ничего не изменилось. Это работает для bootstrap 3?

Comment: насчет bootstrap 3 не уверен, сам работал только с 4ым

Answer (score 0):

Например так:
`<div class="row form-inline form-container">`
*(добавлен собственный класс `form-container`)*

Далее в стилях прописать:

```
.form-container > div{
    margin: 10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: HaZcker, можно ли как-то обойтись без дополнительного файла css? Только средствами bootstrap-а?